# Devise user not saving password (in console)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**Workaround**

In worker.rb:

```
   before_save: set_defaults    
   private
    def set_defaults
      if self.encrypted_password.blank?
        self.encrypted_password = Worker.new.send(:password_digest, password)
      end
      self.has_accepted_terms = false if has_accepted_terms.nil?
      self.live = false if live.nil?
      self.email.downcase!
      self.first_name ||= ""
      self.last_name ||= ""
      self.phone_number ||= ""
      self.last_location_search ||= ""
    end
```

**Update**

Finally found a way to get a password_digest out of it...

Does this give any clues as to what's going on?

```
2.0.0-p481 :016 > Worker.new(password: 'password').encrypted_password
 => ""  # fail
2.0.0-p481 :017 > Worker.new.send(:password_digest, "1234")
 => "$2a$10$mrHUtlUKwKfwIjSJdRjY/.GbLhXKIKOAN9/WVmg3xCXHOJoGJrPMW"
```

**Original**

When I create a Worker (like a User), the password is not being saved

```
> Worker.create(email: "test@gmail32.com", password: "1234", password_confirmation: "1234")
=> #<Worker id: 41, email: "test@gmail32.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-10-01 13:11:27", updated_at: "2015-10-01 13:11:27>
```

This happens any way I try to create a worker. What can cause this? Apparently it can happen if you override a devise method - is that what is happening here?

This is the model, but I can comment out all of it (except the 'Devise' section) and it still doesn't save the password:

```
require 'resque-scheduler'

class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :custom_authenticatable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_save :set_defaults

  def Worker.find_by_credentials(email, password)
    worker = Worker.find_by_email(email.downcase)

    return worker if worker && worker.authenticate(password)

    # worker.errors.add :user_authentication, 'invalid credentials'
    nil
  end

  def authenticate(password)
    live && valid_password?(password)
  end


  def valid_for_custom_authentication?(password)
    live
  end

  private

    def set_defaults
      self.has_accepted_terms = false if has_accepted_terms.nil?
      self.live = false if live.nil?
      self.email.downcase!
    end

end
```

Comment: Your password is too short probably? The minimum length by default is 8 characters (it is set in `config/devise.rb`)

Comment: If you try `create!` instead of `create`, it should raise an error if any of the validations fail. That would be a good place to start trouble shooting.

Comment: @Yury-lebedev: I adjusted the minimum length to 4 a while ago

Comment: @Drenmi: No validations are failing

Comment: I am having this trouble with the old rails 4 app, in the year 2022 :) Any solution of password not being saved?